# How to diagnose windows-specific memory problems in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I made a few changes to a program that uses many vector::resize, vector::reserve, and memcopy operations in order to manipulate a buffer for reading data from files. I ran my unit tests on Linux and they passed with flying colors, however when I ran the same tests on a Windows machine I am seeing a `memory access violation occurred at address 0x0038e000, while attempting to read inaccessible data`.

I have taken some advice I read online and ran Valgrind against my program in an attempt to detect memory leaks/issues, however it came back with "All heap blocks were freed, no leaks are possible".

Any other advice on how to go about seeking out the cause of memory errors in Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: You do not need valgrind. You just need a debugger. Find which line of code causes this error and work from here.

Comment: Run under the debugger, when the program faults inspect the call history / stack frames.

Comment: Try building the program with [address sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try full page heap, it helped me many times.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549561(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This. Windows actually comes with some amazing debugging capabilities, if you know how to use them. Fortunately, Microsoft Press published a book, _Inside Windows Debugging_ by  Tarik Soulami, that provides a nice hands-on introduction to some of the most important tools.